# Triangular dither - What does it mean to say that an input signal is uncorrelated with the dither

Tags: analog-to-digital, sinc, dithering

In the oft-cited ADC dithering appnote: Oversampling Techniques using the TMS320C24x Family http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/spra461, it notes under triangular dither:

> However, this approach requires that the signal does not correlate with the triangular signal. If this cannot be ensured the signal should not change more than $\pm 0.5$ LSB from the expected resolution during an oversample period $k \cdot f_s$.

What does it exactly mean to say that the **input signal does not correlate with the triangular signal**?

(1) Is it that the frequencies in the input spectrum has no overlap with the frequencies in the spectrum of the triangle dither being added?

In the simple case, the triangle wave has a fundamental whose period is $k \cdot f_s$, and all odd-harmonics above that. Nothing below the fundamental. So, does this mean the input signal has to be band-limited to one-half of $\frac1{k \cdot f_s}$? (or comb-filtered to notch out all these odd-harmonics, but that's not an option for most baseband signals)

But then, this sounds like exactly same as the *"or else"* clause in the above; so I guess its not.

(2) Does it make a difference if I make many triangles within the $k \cdot f_s$ period (instead of one big triangle $\frac{k}{2}$ up followed by $\frac{k}{2}$ down)?

One could shift the fundamental of the triangle wave upwards dramatically. (In fact, this paper seems to be heading in that direction: Improving Digital-to-Analog Converter Linearity  by Large High-Frequency Dithering, http://www.precisionmechatronicslab.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/J17c-Preprint2.pdf.)

(3) What happens if my "triangular dither" is not a smooth triangular wave, but a permutation, a random number which has a triangular p.d.f.? The oversampling ADC result should be the same. Then what happens to "correlation"? Now can we say that it surely does not correlate with any signal in the input?

Finally, I suppose I could use an arbitrarily large triangular dither signal. (of course, as long as I am not saturating the signal chain). The dither can have any amplitude more than $\pm \frac12$ LSB. Is that right?

Edit: I read through the papers (cited above) a couple of more times, start to end. They don't define the terms any further, and neither does other literature on the net. How is `correlate` defined? I understand correlation in general, but what would be a metric, and limit of unacceptable correlation in the above?

I don't have a way to fix bugs after launch in this project, I have to make sure I get my understanding right at the outset, or I risk losing the kingdom for a nail. So, thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: @robert-bristow-johnson, thanks for the edits in formatting. But I did go back and undo one specific edit: I changed the quoted text back to 0.5 from $\frac12$, to make the cited quote be [sic]. I did keep the $\pm$, though.

Comment: i think i'll let someone else answer your question.  just remember that dither that is generated independently from your signal getting quantized will always be uncorrelated.  but the resulting quantization error (that is not the dither) will have it's first moment decoupled from the input if it's rectangular p.d.f. dither of 1 LSB added.  but the second moment will still be coupled.  but with triangular p.d.f. both the first and second moments are decoupled from the input signal.